# Show header only when dataView is List in PrimeNG

Tags: angular, gridview, primeng, dataview

I have to show few line in  when the dataView is List and hide it when dataView is Grid.

How to indentify is layout selected is grid or list

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dataview

updates on: 
https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=55296&p=166260#p166260

bug raised:
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/5507#issuecomment-388518425

Comment: So you are using JSF and angular at the same time?

Comment: using primeNG and angular 5

Comment: primeFaces tag has been removed. thnx

Comment: You can easily do it using <ng-template let-car pTemplate="gridItem"> and <ng-template let-car pTemplate="listItem">

Comment: @pArthsavadiya i already have a template for grid and list 
i want to add a line above list bt nt grid.
if i put that line in template then it will repeat but i want it to come just once

Answer (score 0):

You need to patch using JQuery like I did:
Add below code after data loaded from service:

```js
$("<p>Test</p>").insertAfter('p-dataview .ui-dataview-list p-paginator:first');
```

and you need to add some css

```css
.ui-dataview-list p {
    display: block;
}

.ui-dataview-grid p {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks a **bug on primeng**.
I guess that it's because dataview componente has two layout (list and grid) and as it is possible to show both at the same time, it is using two tags and by default, as you can see **at line 21 from dataview.js**, it sets *`"this.layout = 'list';"`*, so we are supossed to set this variable to 'grid' to see gridItem on view.

As DataView.layout is not a `@Input` variable, you can just add the tag `<p-dataViewLayoutOptions>` to switch at view or change line 21 from dataview.js to *`"this.layout = 'grid';"`*

Comment: i raised a bug for this on both github and their website but no reply till now

Comment: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=55296&p=166260#p166260

Comment: For those wondering how to use p-dataView for "grid only", use p-dataGrid instead. p-dataView is meant to combine p-dataList and p-dataGrid in a wrapper container, no to offer them separately because they already exist as separate modules/components.